# Order of DateTime instances is changed after adding the same number of months to both

Tags: c#, datetime

Adding 18 months to two dates `(start < end)` changes the order. After the operation `start > end`:

```
var start = new DateTime(2017, 05, 30, 15, 30, 00);
var end =   new DateTime(2017, 05, 31, 09, 00, 00);

var newStart = start.AddMonths(18);
var newEnd = end.AddMonths(18);

Console.WriteLine(start < end);
Console.WriteLine(newStart < newEnd);

Console.WriteLine(newStart);
Console.WriteLine(newEnd);
```

Gives the following output:

```
True
False
11/30/2018 3:30:00 PM
11/30/2018 9:00:00 AM
```

Adding a different number of months (for example 17) does not exhibit the same behaviour. Which kind of date irregularity is responsible for this?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/dCthCT

Comment: [AddMonths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx): "If the resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the last valid day of the resulting month is used. For example, March 31st + 1 month = April 30th..."

Comment: In the Jewish calendar there are leap months. In a normal year there is a month called "Adar" but in a leap year there are two Adars - "Adar 1" and "Adar 2". A person born on the 20th day of "Adar 1" is born before someone born on the 10th day of "Adar 2", but in a non-leap month year the second person's birthday occurs first. That's how calendars work. There are fuzzy human issues with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which kind of date irregularity is responsible for this?

In the western (Roman) calendar, some months have 31 days, some only 30 days (and February is special and has only 28, sometimes 29, days).

In your example, you end up with November which has only 30 days. So starting from May 31, we cannot go to November 31 (non-existent), so the BCL framework chooses November 30 instead. Then starting with May 30, we also get to November 30.

When the date components are the same, we go to the time-of-day. Here your "old" values are chosen such that the relative order swaps when you go to the new values.

---

I do not think there is any other meaningful way to implement `AddMonths(int)` such that your requirement, "the relative order of two new values obtained by applying the same `.AddMonths(n)` to two old values, should be the same as the relative order of the old values", is met.

In other words, if you see `<` as an inequality (math terms), you cannot apply `.AddMonths(n)` to both sides of the `<` and get a statement that is equivalent to the old one. As a function, "`x` maps to `x.AddMonths(n)`" is not monotone.

...

All right, they *could* have chosen to always prefer **midnight** of the 1st of the next month in each case where the naïve `AddMonths` leads to a non-existent date. (Or chosen that instant minus one *tick*, see  Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment below.) While it would not quite fulfill your wish, it would satisfy a weakly increasing criterion:

> IF `x < y`, THEN `x.AddMonths(n) <= y.AddMonths(n)` (less than or equal)

so that the values never swap, only coincide.

However, Microsoft did not choose that one. Maybe because they felt it was more important that `x.AddMonths(n)` has the same time-of-day component as `x`. Or maybe they felt their way was the most intuitive or natural?

Comment: Sure enough - but shouldn't that leave the order intact and we should end up at December 1st instead?

Comment: @MarkusPalme No.

Comment: @MarkusPalme - if you think through all of the possible edge cases, you'll realise that there's no satisfactory set of rules which will satisfy everyone (e.g. if you change the rule so that it also resets the time component to the last possible moment on the last day of the month, then two unequal times on the 31st of May would become equal after the adjustment) - or with your suggestion (December), two dates in the same month suddenly land in different months.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I overlooked this comment in the documentation. My bad.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx): "If the resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the last valid day of the resulting month is used."

Comment: @MarkusPalme (your first edited comment) Since the BCL cannot know what value you are going to compare with, how would it know whether to choose Dec 01 or Nov 30 when avoiding the impossible Nov 31? Because if your other "old" value was Jun 01, the problem would arise with the opposite choice (Dec 01).

Comment: @MarkusPalme I thought a bit more about it and expanded my answer with considerations on why choosing Dec 01, like you suggest, _could_ actually have been better in some respects.